# Main.Storyboard Frames Not Updated

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, xcode-storyboard

I am currently making an app which I plan to submit to the iOS App Store. Normally, when I update my frames in the Main.Storyboard of Xcode, it stays like that. However, now it does not. Whenever I close the app and reopen it later, the frames are not updated. It looks like this:

[image: Not updated Frames]

After I update the frames, it looks like this (what I want it to look like):

[image: Updated Frames]

The app still looks fine when I run it on the simulator, but I still have 16 warnings in my app. I would like to remove these bugs as (I previously mentioned) I am submitting this app to the iOS App Store. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: when your app loads viewController/UI it automatically adjusts frames according to your constraints specified. Though solution is first remove constraints of that view, then adjust frame correctly, then apply constraints. Happy coding :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)As it showing you have designed the layout in `size class` **width-COMPACT & height-ANY**. If you design your storyboard in `size class` **width-ANY & height-ANY** it will solve your problem.IT also happened with me.I have changed the size class & updated constraints of all ViewControllers.

2)It now shows a blank view controller. However, You will not get any warnings

3) Now You can make it visible by changing size class of the views inside the controller
**select the view ->go to attribute inspector->go to bottom-> select installed & delete earlier selected size class**

4)**Do it for all views & update the constraints**

Comment: It now shows a blank view controller. However, I am not getting any warnings. I guess this will do for now. Thanks @RKP

Comment: You can make it visible by changing size class of the views inside the controller.

Comment: Sorry. I have little experience wth this. How should j do that?

Comment: select the view ->go to attribute inspector->go to bottom-> select installed & delete earlier selected size class

Comment: Ok. I will try that and let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @RKP. I no longer have the problem!

Comment: :please edit your answer to include how to make the ViewController visible again so it will be easier for others who find this question.