# xcode 7.2 resets views to X 0 Y 0 240 wide 128 high

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have an extremely complex view in a storyboard that is causing me headaches.  Every time I reopen the storyboard, all of the views (and there are many) are reset to x=0, y=0, width=240, height=128.  What's worse is, the "Update Frames" option is seldom available in the "Resolve Auto Layout Issues" menu.

Has anyone else experienced this and determined a surefire fix?  It takes me a half hour to reset the views to a reasonable point so I can work with them again.

By the way, it works perfectly fine when running in either the simulator or device - it's just impossible for me to edit it.

Comment: Do you used size class

Comment: I mostly edit in any/any, but I do have changes for compact/any

Comment: Make sure you design in any any..and edit in size class whichever you needed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351106/main-storyboard-frames-not-updated/34352860?noredirect=1#comment56499000_34352860 also refer this ans it might help you

Comment: I have removed all evidence of another size class (from all views and constraints), but I still cannot update frames :(