# How to fix missing constraint while restarting xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode7.1

I have made two storyboards: one for iPhone and another for iPad. To create the iPad storyboard I have used size class wRegular hRegular. After fixing all my constraint issues, it works perfectly in preview, but when I restart Xcode some constraints are misplaced.

[Screen shot misplaced constraint while restart xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkY8P.png)

[Screen shot after updating the frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcXMd.png)

Comment: use update frame or update constraints after you do so. and constraint can't be alter by itself, u r doing something.

Comment: I'm using the update frame It  works but while restart xcode frame be set same place as before.

Comment: Plese refer my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351106/main-storyboard-frames-not-updated/34352860#34352860

Comment: can I see screenshot, so I could judge better.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot please check it.

Comment: Monilal@ have you refered my answer

Comment: yes I have gone through your answer and done as such but still I'm getting same. Parent view controller already install I'm unstalling that and installing r Regular h Regular weather i am doing correct

Answer (score 0):

just a suggestion , if you are using the same UI for both iPad and iPhone , better to use a single storyboard for both .

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'm knowing to use single storyboard for both is better than to create two but this is also not wrong method to do so, will you please answer me the current question.

Answer (score 0):

- The Basic concept of using Size class is whatever your Base design.it
  should be designed in `wAny hAny`.
- Now it you want any perticular view should be displayed in perticular
  size class then only it can be added to that size class eg. if you
  want label should be displayed in iPad then you should add it
  `wRegular hRegular` Size class.As label added to `wRegular hRegular` it will only visible for iPad 7 not visible in iPhones.
- So what you need to do is Redesign your `StoryBoard` in `wAny hAny` and
  add `constraints` to it.
- You can Also refer my answer which has some description [Main.Storyboard Frames Not Updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351106/main-storyboard-frames-not-updated/34352860#34352860)

Comment: Thanks @Rohit for your reply, as i mentioned before i have made another storyboard for Iphone by using w Any h Any but after giving more effort i was  not able to make responsive view for both iphone and ipad then i have chooses to use size class w Regular h Regular for ipad and made another storyboard  which works perfectly once i update frame but when i restart the xcode again ipad frame be set as it was before,so will you please let me know weather i can make responsive view wihout using size class

Comment: I don't think it will be a better solution.It will solve your problem for time being,But it will give you pain some where in future.There are many concerns of using single StoryBoard.Better is to solve this problem using single storyBoard.

Comment: Using a single StoryBoard is motive behind introducing size classes

Comment: ok, i am doing as you told with single storyboard,i will let you know later thanks for your reply